# Ciclo de Vida da ViewBag em C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Eu sei que o ciclo de vida da `ViewBag` do `C# MVC`, é por requisição.

#### Dúvida

Se eu setar uma `ViewBag` com mesmo nome em diversos `controllers`, existe a possibilidade da informação setada ser lida / interpretada de forma incorreta na `View`?

#### Exemplo

- Requisição X acessa a `ControllerA` faz `ViewBag.Mensagem = "SOP"`
- Requisição Y acessa a `ControllerA` faz `ViewBag.Mensagem = "SO"`
- Requisição W acessa a `ControllerB` faz `ViewBag.Mensagem = "SOPortuguês"`

Porém, a requisição Y, é renderizada primeiro, então por ocorrer ao usar a `ViewBag.Mensagem` na `View`, aparecer `SOPortuguês` em vez de `SO`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Uma `ViewBag` transfere dados do controller para a view, idealmente dados temporários que não estão incluídos em um modelo.
2. A vida de uma `ViewBag` dura apenas durante a solicitação http atual. Os valores de uma `ViewBag` serão nulos se o redirecionamento ocorrer.

Ou seja, o valor da `ViewBag` é único dentro de um Request, sendo assim, para cada chamada você terá uma valor diferente em seu caso.